# Shortening/Optimizing some code

Tags: vb.net, optimization

I have the following section of code, which works, but I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to write this, perhaps with less lines of code. My project consists of 4 radio buttons, and I'm trying to save the value of which of the 4 is selected.

I ask, because I have multiple sets of 4-10 radio buttons that need settings saved.

Code:

```
Public sTime5 As Integer
Public sTime10 As Integer
Public sTime30 As Integer
Public sTime60 As Integer

    'Set Time
    If RADtime5.Checked = True Then
        sTime5 = 1
    Else
        sTime5 = 0
    End If
    If RADtime10.Checked = True Then
        sTime10 = 1
    Else
        sTime10 = 0
    End If
    If RADtime30.Checked = True Then
        sTime30 = 1
    Else
        sTime30 = 0
    End If
    If RADtime60.Checked = True Then
        sTime60 = 1
    Else
        sTime60 = 0
    End If

    My.Settings.SearchTime5 = sTime5
    My.Settings.SearchTime10 = sTime10
    My.Settings.SearchTime30 = sTime30
    My.Settings.SearchTime60 = sTime60
```

Comment: Are you aware that a My.Settings value can have a Boolean type? So you could have `My.Settings.SearchTime5 = RADtime5.Checked` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx), when Visual Basic converts Boolean values to numeric types, False becomes 0 and True becomes -1. So, you can try something like the following

```
    My.Settings.SearchTime5 = -CInt(RADtime5.Checked)
    My.Settings.SearchTime10 = -CInt(RADtime10.Checked)
    My.Settings.SearchTime30 = -CInt(RADtime30.Checked)
    My.Settings.SearchTime60 = -CInt(RADtime60.Checked)
```

or you can use [Math.Abs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx) to get their absolute values.

**EDIT**

When Visual Basic converts numeric data type values to Boolean, 0 becomes False and all other values become True. To read the values, you can do the following

```
    RADtime5.Checked = CInt(My.Settings.SearchTime5)
    RADtime10.Checked = CInt(My.Settings.SearchTime10)
    RADtime30.Checked = CInt(My.Settings.SearchTime30)
    RADtime60.Checked = CInt(My.Settings.SearchTime60)
```

Comment: So, this should directly store the value of each Radio button, as 0 or 1, into the My.Setting?

Can I use the same to read the setting?

 -CInt(RADtime60.Checked) =My.Settings.SearchTime60

Comment: Yes, the code will let you store the values directly. To read them, check the EDIT.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I guess the same would work for CheckBoxes then too. Where 1 is checked and 0 is unchecked.

Comment: You're welcome, you can use the same logic with any component which has boolean data type.

Comment: It works perfect thank you! I'm wondering if now there may be a way to reduce this even further, and only have 1 .setting to store the search interval, as opposed to 4 different .settings, one for each time slot.

Comment: You can store other data types as well in application settings. If you want a single variable for all the states, try storing a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the control using a function like this:

```
    My.Settings.SearchTime5 = GetCheck(5)
    My.Settings.SearchTime10 = GetCheck(10)
    My.Settings.SearchTime30 = GetCheck(30)
    My.Settings.SearchTime60 = GetCheck(60)

Private Function LabelControl(ByVal index As Integer) As Integer
    Dim rad As RadioButton = CType(Me.Controls.Find("RADtime" + index.ToString, True).First, RadioButton)
    Return If(rad.Checked, 1, 0)
End Function
```

But it may be easier to add a reference to your controls into a list if you are referencing them often

Comment: I reference them once when loaded, and once when the setting is applied. This may actually work, I will have to do some experimenting with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a shared class called SettingsFormatter, with a shared method called `BooleanToInteger` (accepting a boolean value, returning an integer). Then call:

```
My.Settings.SearchTime5 = SettingsFormatter.BooleanToInteger(RADtime5.Checked)
My.Settings.SearchTime10 = SettingsFormatter.BooleanToInteger(RADtime10.Checked)
My.Settings.SearchTime30 = SettingsFormatter.BooleanToInteger(RADtime30.Checked)
My.Settings.SearchTime60 = SettingsFormatter.BooleanToInteger(RADtime60.Checked)
```

Here is code for `BooleanToInteger`:

```
Public Shared Function BooleanToInteger(value As Boolean) As Integer
  Return If(value, 1, 0)
End Function
```

You can later declare any other custom conversions that you need to reuse across the project.